# Info code sql present in the log file. How can I use It?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm new of sql Language.
I was able (with some forum support) to import my .dmp file into a new oracle database.

This is the log: (whitout errors)

http://m.uploadedit.com/b044/1422636429519.txt

But I need to know If I can use the code that is present in the log file from point:

"CREATE FORCE VIEW "MX"."VRBD_RICBDTUTENTI"

That code can be useful?
How can I try to use that code on the database imported?

thanks

Comment: Well it says it was created with warnings.

Comment: The views have been created, but may be invalid still; they will attempt to compile when referenced, or you can `alter view ... compile`; and you can query the `all_errors` view to see what's wrong. Could have been references to things that didn't exist yet, or could be more serious. You should also consider using data pump rather than the old export/import.

Comment: For some reason, the file can't be seen. Please fix this (you could copy relevant parts in here)!